# Xamarin Forms ListView inside RelativeLayout

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to programmatically build a layout that has a full-screen ListView with a full-screen background image. The image displays just fine, but I can't see the two list entries at the bottom of the ListView when I scroll down.

```
        logo = new Image
        {
            Source = "bg.png",
            Scale = 0.5,
            Opacity = 0
        };
        var relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(logo,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width / 2 - GetWidth(parent, logo) / 2),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Height / 2 - GetHeight(parent, logo) / 2));
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(listView, Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => 0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => 0));
        Content = relativeLayout;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your post didn't contains the code about the entry . Please provide the relevant part .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This is the pertinent code that builds Content of the page.

Comment: Where did you define the Entry ? You could provide the full code or share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Ah, sorry! By "entries" I mean list entries. I have edited the post.

Comment: I mean where did you define the  entry list ? I couldn't see any relevant code .